# Need to import data from XML to SQL using Windows Form (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, xml, winforms

This is the code to import the data from a XML document to SQL, what I don't know how to do is if the name of the XML attribute matches one of the SQL attributes on the table, import the data that only matches the attributes, where if it doesn't matches import a null data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;


namespace XML_A_BD
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string archivo = "";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strConn = "Data Source=(LOCAL);Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=true";
        string strSQL = "SELECT name FROM sys.databases order by name";
        SqlConnection scnnRegistro = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, scnnRegistro);
        try
        {
            scnnRegistro.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = scmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                comboBoxBase.Items.Add(sdr.GetString(0).ToString());
            }
            sdr.Close();
            comboBoxBase.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (SqlException expSql)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(expSql.ToString());
        }

    }

    private void comboBoxBase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strConn = "Data Source=(LOCAL);Initial Catalog =master;Integrated Security=SSPI";
        string strSQL = "SELECT name FROM " + comboBoxBase.SelectedItem.ToString();
        strSQL += ".sys.objects where type = 'U' order by name";
        MessageBox.Show(strSQL);
        SqlConnection scnnRegistro = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, scnnRegistro);
        try
        {
            scnnRegistro.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = scmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                comboBoxTabla.Items.Add(sdr.GetString(0).ToString());
            }
            sdr.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException expSql)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(expSql.ToString());
        }
        comboBoxTabla.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void buttonSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Seguro que desea salir?", "Salir", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void buttonSeleccionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog abrir = new OpenFileDialog();
            abrir.Filter = "Archivos XML(*.xml)|*.xml|Todos los archivos(*.*)|*.*";
            abrir.FilterIndex = 0;
            abrir.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            //guardar.Filename = tabla;
            if (abrir.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                archivo = abrir.FileName;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void buttonCargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool bandera = false;


        //Esto lee los nombres de la tabla
        /*System.Xml.XmlTextReader lee = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(archivo);
        string contents = "";
        while (lee.Read())
        {
            lee.MoveToContent();
            if (lee.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                contents += "<" + lee.Name + ">\n";
                */
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(archivo);
            XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/" + comboBoxBase.SelectedItem.ToString() + "/" + comboBoxTabla.SelectedItem.ToString());

            foreach (XmlNode node in dataNodes)
            {
                string sql = "";

                XmlNodeList lstNodos = node.ChildNodes;
                MessageBox.Show(lstNodos.Count.ToString());
                int contador = 0;
                string[] atributos = new string[lstNodos.Count];
                string[] valores = new string[lstNodos.Count];
                /*string[] nombres = new string[lstNodos.Count];*/
                sql = "Insert into " + comboBoxBase.SelectedItem.ToString();
                sql = sql + ".." + comboBoxTabla.SelectedItem.ToString() + " values (";
                foreach (XmlNode nodoHijo in lstNodos)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(nodoHijo.Name); //Nombre de la etiqueta del nodo
                    MessageBox.Show(nodoHijo.InnerText);
                    atributos[contador] = "@" + nodoHijo.Name;
                    valores[contador] = nodoHijo.InnerText;
                    sql = sql + (++contador < lstNodos.Count ? "@" + nodoHijo.Name + "," : "@" + nodoHijo.Name);
                }
                sql = sql + ")";
                //sql = "insert into banco..prestamo values(1,1,6,3000.00)";
                MessageBox.Show(sql);
                try
                {
                    string conexion = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI";
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conexion);
                    //using (command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn));
                    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    for (int i = 0; i < lstNodos.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //comando.Parameters.AddWithValue(atributos[i], (i < 3 ? int.Parse(valores)))
                        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue(atributos[i], valores[i]);
                        MessageBox.Show(atributos[i] + " " + valores[i]);
                    }
                    conn.Open();
                    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (SqlException expSql)
                {
                    bandera = true;
                    MessageBox.Show(expSql.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        if (bandera == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Se omitieron valores repetidos. Exportacion completa.", "Exito", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exportacion a SQL correcta", "Exito", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<cliente>
  <cliente>
    <no_cliente>6</no_cliente>
    <nombre>Luis</nombre>
    <ap_paterno>Franco</ap_paterno>
    <ap_materno>Cárdenas</ap_materno>
    <calle>Sadi Carnot</calle>
    <ciudad_cliente>Distrito Federal</ciudad_cliente>
    <password>6</password>
  </cliente>
  <cliente>
    <no_cliente>7</no_cliente>
    <nombre>Alberto</nombre>
    <ap_paterno>Marín</ap_paterno>
    <ap_materno>Pérez</ap_materno>
    <calle>Principal</calle>
    <ciudad_cliente>Distrito Federal</ciudad_cliente>
    <password>7</password>
  </cliente>
  <cliente>
    <no_cliente>8</no_cliente>
    <nombre>Roberto</nombre>
    <ap_paterno>López</ap_paterno>
    <ap_materno>Mora</ap_materno>
    <calle>Altavista</calle>
    <ciudad_cliente>Guadalajara</ciudad_cliente>
    <password>8</password>
  </cliente>
  <cliente>
    <no_cliente>9</no_cliente>
    <nombre>Andrea</nombre>
    <ap_paterno>Carrillo</ap_paterno>
    <ap_materno>Méndez</ap_materno>
    <calle>Primavera</calle>
    <ciudad_cliente>Monterrey</ciudad_cliente>
    <password>9</password>
  </cliente>
  <cliente>
    <no_cliente>10</no_cliente>
    <nombre>Daniela</nombre>
    <ap_paterno>Torres</ap_paterno>
    <ap_materno>Gordillo</ap_materno>
    <calle>Ing. Militares</calle>
    <ciudad_cliente>Naucalpan</ciudad_cliente>
    <password>10</password>
  </cliente>
  <cliente>
    <no_cliente>11</no_cliente>
    <nombre>Pedro</nombre>
    <ap_paterno>López</ap_paterno>
    <ap_materno>Zamorano</ap_materno>
    <calle>Barracuda</calle>
    <ciudad_cliente>Veracruz</ciudad_cliente>
    <password>11</password>
  </cliente>
</cliente>
```

It has to transform any XML document into the table on SQL. If it matches the names of the attributes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please check [ask] for information on getting the most out of your questions.  You should try to get a [mcve] together to isolate what exactly your problem is.

Comment: It's because I don't really know where to put the code or what to modify. I know it's on **private void buttonCargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)** well inside that code.

Comment: @Marco Diez Barroso Zamudio Can you post your XML (all of it) to your question above (Edit you question and add the XML, don't put the XML in the comments here)

Comment: There is the XML, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you want to import the XML data into the corresponding columns (fields) in an SQL table...

Create the table and a Stored procedure on SQL Server

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[cliente]    Script Date: 21/04/2016 01:08:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cliente](
    [no_cliente] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [nombre] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ap_paterno] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ap_materno] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [calle] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ciudad_cliente] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [password] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO


/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_InsertXMLData]    Script Date: 21/04/2016 01:08:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_InsertXMLData] (@InputXML xml)
as
begin

    MERGE  cliente AS main
    USING (select Row.id.value('@no_cliente','[nvarchar](MAX)') as no_cliente, Row.id.value('@nombre','[nvarchar](MAX)') as nombre, Row.id.value('@ap_paterno','[nvarchar](MAX)') as ap_paterno, Row.id.value('@ap_materno','[nvarchar](MAX)') as ap_materno
            , Row.id.value('@calle','[nvarchar](MAX)') as calle, Row.id.value('@ciudad_cliente','[nvarchar](MAX)') as ciudad_cliente, Row.id.value('@password','[nvarchar](MAX)') as password
                from @InputXML.nodes('/Root/CSVDataRecord') as Row(id)) as stage
    ON main.password=stage.password
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET main.no_cliente=stage.no_cliente, main.nombre=stage.nombre, main.ap_paterno=stage.ap_paterno, main.ap_materno=stage.ap_materno , main.calle=stage.calle , main.ciudad_cliente=stage.ciudad_cliente, main.password=stage.password
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT  (no_cliente, nombre, ap_paterno, ap_materno, calle, ciudad_cliente, password) 
        VALUES (stage.no_cliente, stage.nombre, stage.ap_paterno, stage.ap_materno, stage.calle, stage.ciudad_cliente, stage.password);
end

GO
```

Here is the code

Usings

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Code... UPDATE!!!

I have modified the LINQ statement so that if an element (in your XML) is missing, the new XAttribute [sent to the Stored Procedure] defaults to null......

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string strXML = File.ReadAllText("xml.xml");

        XDocument xmlsrcdoc = XDocument.Parse(strXML);

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("<Your connection string>"))
        {
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            connection.Open();

            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "SP_InsertXMLData";
            XElement XMLData = new XElement("Root",
                from xml in xmlsrcdoc.Descendants("cliente").Descendants("cliente")
                select new XElement("CSVDataRecord",
                    new XAttribute("no_cliente", (string)xml.Element("no_cliente") ?? ""),
                    new XAttribute("nombre", (string)xml.Element("nombre") ?? ""),
                    new XAttribute("ap_paterno", (string)xml.Element("ap_paterno") ?? ""),
                    new XAttribute("ap_materno", (string)xml.Element("ap_materno") ?? ""),
                    new XAttribute("calle", (string)xml.Element("calle") ?? ""),
                    new XAttribute("ciudad_cliente", (string)xml.Element("ciudad_cliente") ?? ""),
                    new XAttribute("password", (string)xml.Element("password") ?? "")
                )
            );

            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@InputXML",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Xml,
                Value = new SqlXml(XMLData.CreateReader())
            });

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
```

And here is a picture of SQL Table after data import....

[image: View of SQL Table after import]

Save your XML to a file (xml.xml) in the same folder as your .EXE.... Hope that helps.

Comment: It kinda helped me, but the thing it's that no matter which XML Document load, it has to see if it matches on the table, if it doesn't it won't appear on SQL, it will show NULL.

So if I give another XML it'll put other values until it fills the table.

Comment: Not sure what you want there, i am assuming that some of the elements in your XML might NOT always be present (might need to see an example).... I have updated my answer with a possible solution....

Comment: Sorry im on my mobile.             What it needs to do its to read any XML an if it matches a name of an attribute it will import the data, if it doesn't it will appear on sql as null where the attributes didn't appear on the XML.                                                    XML

EmployeeID 123456                               
Country                                 
Phone                                    
SQL

EmployeeID 123456
Name       Null 
Last Name  Null